# elastic search is not returning record for nearby input date

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5, elasticsearch-query

Below is index definition and sample record with query to search

***Looking for records matching name as "aaa" and date onwards 2020-01-01 so I should not get any record as there is no date record in elastic search >2020-01-05 ***
However with below input I am still getting record from elastic search as if it considers only name field query.

Create Index
POST
http://localhost:9200/gauss_index1/date_format

```
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "date": {
        "type":   "date",
        "format": "yyyy-MM-dd"
      },
      "name":{
        "type":   "text"
          
      }
    }
  }
}Add records : 
PUT http://localhost:9200/gauss_index1/date_format/1
{

      "date": "2019-01-05",
      "name": "aaa"
}
PUT http://localhost:9200/gauss_index1/date_format/2
{

      "date": "2019-02-05",
      "name": "bbb"
}

PUT http://localhost:9200/gauss_index1/date_format/3
{
      "date": "2019-03-05",
      "name": "ccc"
}

Search 
POST http://localhost:9200/gauss_index1/date_format/_search

 {
    "query": {
        "function_score": {
            "functions": [
                {
                    "gauss": {
                        "date": {
                            "origin": "2020-03-01",
                            "scale": "10d",
                            "offset": "5d"
                        }
                    }
                }
            ],
            "query": {
                "multi_match": {
                    "query": "aaa"
                    "fields": [
                        "name"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


 **Returns only record matching with name aaa but as mentioned in gauss origin is march 1 onwards needs to be searched 
 but I am getting records of only conditin matching name equals "aaa"
```

Comment: The gauss function will not exclude document 1, but simply give it a score of 0 since its date is outside of the defined gauss bounds. That's how the function-score query works. What are you trying to achieve exactly?

Comment: e.g. in Elastisearch db multiple documents added with  "date" as  2019-01-05,2019-02-05  so need to find a next date e.g. for query input  2019-01-06 & name as "bbb" I should get document with id 2 as I am scaling by 10 days.But here I am getting all the records I added. Also I have to keep on incrementing the date range till I get closest matching date i.e the reason offset 5 is configured in query

Answer (score 0):

As @Val pointed out, the assigned score will be 0 -- you can verify this by running your query with `?explain=true`.

If you do want to strictly exclude such docs, apply a range filter:

```
{
  "query": {
    "function_score": {
      "functions": [
        {
          "gauss": {
            ...
          }
        }
      ],
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "range": {                     <-------
                "date": {
                  "gte": "2020-03-01",
                  "format": "yyyy-MM-dd"
                }
              }
            },
            {
              "multi_match": {
                ...
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I need date search to happen incrementally inside elastic search . e.g. I start with feb 1 then es should search documents till date 10 feb if does not find one then should add 5 days offset i.e. feb 15 likewise till I get at least 1 result